# React Native Android App consumes 30mA per hour even though app is in background

Tags: android, react-native

Performed current drain test on sample (Welcome to React Native) app when the app was in background for an hour and the results are as follows:

```
Sample application with RN version 34 : 31.54mA
Sample application with RN version 22 : 24.60mA
```

Where as the sample native android app only consumes about `10mA` in the same scenario.

Tools Used :

```
Power monitor (H/w)
Power tool (S/w)
```

1) Can anybody confirm the above test and explain the reason behind high current drain ?

2) Is it normal for react native apps to have higher current drain values as compared to the native android app?

```
React Native version: RN 0.22 and RN 0.34
Platform : Android
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running the React Native app bundled or using the NPM server? Probably that is making the difference, since there is a socket always connected.

Comment: @SandroMachado This test is performed on the Release build of the Signed APK i.e., the JS bundle is not served via the NPM server but is present in the assets of the application itself.

Comment: you should add that information to the question.

Comment: Asking colleagues at fb.

Comment: @MartinKonicek Really Appreciate man

Comment: @MartinKonicek, do you have updates on this?

Comment: @MartinKonicek Do you have any good news for us?

Comment: At first glance, I can see that the sample app leaves the accelerometer running when it is configured as a debug app, but has it off if it is a release app. I'm going to assume you used the release config, since you mentioned that in your second comment, so my questions are did you make a native android app similar to the sample? Is there a version of the react-native sample app that doesn't use any react-native libs? What power monitor did you use?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue internally at fb. Do you still hit this?

Comment: Sorry about the very late reply! Forgot to report back here and now came across this question again.

Comment: @MartinKonicek by 'Doesn't seem to be an issue internally at fb' you mean that you do similar power usage-related benchmarks and you haven't picked something similar up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do not know the internals, I believe the following statement is a good hypothesis;

Even when you have installed the application in release mode (in other words, there is no npm server and the app uses local .jsbundle) React Native has to keep two things working;

1. A native thread to respond to whatever our JS code required (draw this, get geolocation etc.)
2. A Javascript VM to interpret our code. (.jsbundle file included with the APK)

I believe, due to this added load, a react native app should consume more power, assuming everything else is equal.